# How I can use background-image on container that does not have content?

Tags: html, css, web

I have this structure:

```html
 <div id="container">
        <div id="header></div>
        <div id="content>
            <div id="sidebar"></div>
            <div id="main"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

I need to use background-image on container, but it does not have any content. Only header, sidebar, and main have content. How I can do it without `position: absolute` or specifying height in pixels?

`min-height` is useful, but I want to try dynamic size.

Comment: try defining min-height or height to your container

Comment: And you want it to do what? Should the container take the dimensions of the image? Should the image crop to some arbitrary values?

Comment: Please check this link:-http://html-tuts.com/negative-offset-background-position/

Comment: `.container` has content: header and sidebar, as long as they're in the flow (not fixed or absolutely positioned for example). Do both the latter have already opaque background images and thus the one on container is displayed under them and you want it to displayed somewhere (padding-top'd be fine) or something else? A working snippet would be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others had noticed, it doesn't make much sense to have a container without content... but if you really wanna do this, you could use a `padding` on your `#container` to give it the size of the image:

```css
#container {
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/g/800/600/);
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% * (600/800));
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="header></div>
    <div id="content>
        <div id="sidebar"></div>
        <div id="main"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

This way, the container will have the same aspect ratio as your background image.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jordinebot/ktko01gf/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't show a background on a container that does not have content or specific height/width because it makes no sense.

A background means the "backside of the content", if the content don't have a size where you put the background? :)

Comment: children's block with content != content?

Comment: If the children block is empty or don't have a height/width like your code it means it will not have height set.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rough idea of how much content the container is going to contain, you don't need to specify an exact height for it. Instead, consider using the `min-height` attribute like this:

```css
#container {
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you're setting a background, it means that it will be displayed behind all of the content within the area that the content is in. For this reason, a minimum height must be specified for it to display the background without requiring any fixed, unchangeable height and without any content in the container.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
background: url("image.png") no-repeat 105% 105%;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#container {
min-height: 200px;
background-image: url('your-image.png');
}
```